# Extract integers from formula(string) using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a column with formulas. I need to extract only the integers present in the formula and put them in the next row. For this formula,

```
Column A
(((23-22)/23)*100)
```

The output expected is as below without 100

```
   Column A
   23
   22
```

I want to implement this in sql. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Edit1: The integers in the formula are actually the ids from another table. I need to join the tables on the IDs present in this formula

```
Table 1          Table 2
Tbl1ID           Tabl2Id    Formula
22               1          (((23-22)/23)*100)
23               2          24 + 25
24               
25
```

I have seen to it that Table 1 does not have Tbl1ID as 100.

Edit2: Probably my approach is not right. The actual requirement is I need to replace the integers with a name associated to the id.

```
Table 1            Table 2                          Table 3(Required)
Tbl1ID    Name     Tbl2Id    Formula                Col1
  23      a         1       (((23-22)/23)*100)      (((a-b)/a)*100)
  22      b
```

Comment: Always Your string is same format? Like above.

Comment: why not 100? can you please illustrate with another example

Comment: This is a job for a parser, not a database.  Take your column to Java, C#, Python, etc. and do the work there.

Comment: @Buddi No. I can have formula like just 5+2. I need to remove these operators and parenthesis.

Comment: Use PATINDEX inside a loop. Put it inside a scalar UDF.

Comment: But do you only need the numbers or also the operators? Why is * 100 ignored? What evil being designed this?

Comment: @Andrew yes i need only the numbers. And like i have mentioned, the numbers are ids from another table need to join these 2 tables on this.

Comment: You have ignored the question about * 100 twice already. That only makes receiving help quite harder....

Comment: @Andrew  100 is part of the formula. Not any id in the other table required to join.

Comment: Yes, you said that, but how can you tell? What if it's * 99 or * 101? Are the Ids less than a specific value?

Comment: @Andrew It will always be *100 that is for sure. Ids can be upto any value.

Comment: What if the Id is 100?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TEST TABLE (TBL1ID INT)
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('22')
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('23')
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('24')
INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES ('25')

DECLARE @NUM TABLE (INTE INT)
DECLARE @FORM VARCHAR(100)='(((23-22)/23)*100)',@VAL VARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE( PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@FORM))>0
BEGIN
    SET @VAL=(SELECT LEFT(VAL,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', VAL+'A')-1) FROM(
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@FORM, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @FORM), LEN(@FORM)) VAL )X)
    INSERT INTO @NUM VALUES( @VAL)
    SET @FORM= SUBSTRING(@FORM, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @FORM)+LEN(@VAL),LEN(@FORM))
END

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM @NUM WHERE INTE IN (SELECT * FROM @TEST)
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and if i'm facing any issues..will get back :)